# MAC address of router changes when i connect to VPN

Tags: man-in-the-middle, vpn, router, mac-address, mac-spoofing

If I connect to my VPN and then run `arp -a` the MAC address of my router changes to `00:00:00:00:00:02`. Is this normal behaviour? What is the reasoning behind this?

Furthermore a MAC address spoofing is only of real concern when there are *more than one* devices on the network, and they try to become the MITM correct?

Comment: *"... when there are more than one devices on the network ..."* - if there is only a single device it cannot even be called a network, it is a device only.

Comment: Did you know the answer to my actual question?

Comment: And the reason i word the question that way, is cause there _could_ have been more than one device connected at one time, but at the moment my machine connected to the VPN it is the only one on the network

Comment: Very likely there is at least the router in the network - which is also a network device. Apart from that: what OS you are using and what kind of VPN. And what is the complete output of `arp -a`?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, The VPN is expressVPN which uses an open-source implementation of *IKEv2* and this is the complete output: 
`? (192.168.0.1) at 00:00:00:00:00:02 [ether] on wlp1s0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you spin up a VPN tunnel, the VPN tunnel becomes your new primary route.  If the router address remained as your physical router MAC, then you would not be routing traffic through the VPN, and you would not be protected.  The virtual router your VPN sets up is using the synthetic MAC address 00:00:00:00:00:02.  The change you're seeing is the correct and expected behavior when activating a VPN.

And you are correct, MAC spoofing requires an attacking device on the same LAN.  What you are seeing is not MAC spoofing, regardless.

Comment: +1.  This is what I thought, but I wasn't sure.  Out of curiosity, if the VPN is configured for split-tunneling, would this answer still apply?

Comment: No, if it is split-tunneling, the default would remain the hardware router but specific routes for the VPN-targeted subnets would be made with the virtual MAC as their destination.

Comment: Is this behavior in the answer specific to IPsec? I have not seen this before with other protocols.

Comment: @multithr3at3d it applies to IPSec tunnel mode, not IPSec transport mode (but the latter is pretty rare to run across).  I'm sure other protocols may handle it differently...